# Which method shall I select to delete many to many relationship data

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Which method shall I select to delete many to many relationship data.

I have intermediate table where I need to delete multiple records based on the request payload.

My payload will be like :

```
{
    userid : 1,
    transaction : [b,c]
}
```

How should I write my controller class so I can read this request body.

```
@DeleteMapping(“/remove/{id}")
public EntityModel<TransictionDto> deleteTtransictionByUserId(
        @PathVariable(required=false,name ="userDetails")String userString
    

) throws IOException {
    return null; 
}
```

Here I am not able to get my request header or payload.  What will be the best way or method in controller class where I can get the request header and pass

To service calss.

Or

What is the best way to delete many to many relationship from table.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete by **repository**  like

```
@Repository
public interface TransictionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transiction, Long> {
      void deleteByUserId(Long userId);

}
```

In your controller

```
@Autowired
TransictionRepository transictionRepository;

@DeleteMapping(“/remove/{id}")
public EntityModel<TransictionDto> deleteTtransictionByUserId(
        @PathVariable(required=false,name ="userDetails")String userString
    transictionRepository.deleteByUserId(userString)

) throws IOException {
    return null; 
}
```